# Facebook Connect button for Zend Framework site

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to add a [Facebook Connect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Connect) button to my Zend Framework web site.

After I click on Facebook Connect connect button the popup with email and password fields opens. But when I send email and password to login with Facebook the popup doesn't close and reload the same page where the Facebook Connect button was.
Any idea?

Comment: So you have a page A1 with FB Connect, then you click the button and a popup window A2 (or lightbox?) opens asking for login, you put your credentials and page A2 (popup) reloads showing the content of page A1?

Answer (score 0):

If you have done everything else correctly then for sure, it is because the page where you have put the Facebook Connect button code, is not able to read the xd_receiver file.

Correctly specify that file please or put below line somewhere inside the body tag:

```
**script** src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/XdCommReceiver.js" type="text/javascript"> /**script**
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded the xd_reciever file in the correct location, just double check you can actually access it with your browser and your web server configuration doesn't prevent it.  I had this issue and it was because my web server was configured to ignore resources at that particular path.